# Multiple filter parameters in API endpoint - DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I am using [Django rest framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) for my REST API. I have endpoint where are some parameters for filtering, something like this:

```
# in my view
from_date = self.request.query_params.get('from', None)
to_date = self.request.query_params.get('to', None)
category = self.request.query_params.get('category', None)
color = self.request.query_params.get('color', None)
```

Then I have if/else code where I am selecting the data. For the first time there was only a two parameters so it was ok, but then I added more parameters for filtering and now I think this code is not looking very good and I think there is a need for some optimization. Moreover combination of different parameters is not working now.

Actual code (in my view):

```
if from_date is not None and to_date is not None:
    something = Something.objects.filter(send_date__range=(from_date, to_date))
elif category:
    something = Something.objects.filter(values__something__category__name__iexact=category)
elif color:
    something = Something.objects.filter(values__something__color__name__iexact=color)
else:
    something = Something.objects.all()
```

Is there any option, built-in to the DRF or some type of combined filtering in Django how can I combine parameters into one big query taking into account that values can be None?

For example, if user send **from_date** and **to_date** query filter data using dates. But user also want filter data using **from_date**, **to_date** and **color** or other combination of parameters. Some parameters can be omitted. The code is only minimal version. I have more parameters and I don't wanna write if and else for every combination of parameters.

Something like **(but if one of the values is None query will work without this value)**:

```
Something.objects.filter(send_date__range=(from_date, to_date))
    .filter(values__something__category__name__iexact=category)
    .filter(values__something__color__name__iexact=color)
```

Comment: So for example, 
if from_date and to_date is None, Then what default value are you going to give for the query to work out? or what exactly do you want the query to do?

Comment: I will extend my question. Give me a minute

Comment: Ok, added some info. I don't wanna write if/else for every combination of parameters because user can filter data using date and color, or only color, color and category and so on

Comment: just gona recommend django filter (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/) it's a crazy comprehensive solution to filtering in django and integrates easily with DRF

Comment: I was thinking of the same, using django-filters, but I was lost in thought if there is some other simpler solution.

Comment: Thanks @bryan60, I will check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Translating parameters into query filters cannot be fully automated as only you know what parameters should filter on what field in which way. But unless you have crazy combinations of `or` and `and` criteria, it should be pretty straightforward as you can chain `.filter()` calls without any restrictions as long as you want to `and` all criteria:

```
something = Something.objects.all()
if from_date and to_date:
    something = something.filter(send_date__range=(from_date, to_date))
if category:
    something = something.filter(values__something__category__name__iexact=category)
if color:
    something = something.filter(values__something__color__name__iexact=color)
```

This covers all combinations and looks quite manageable, no?

If you need to `or` (some of) your criteria, you need [Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects), which however you can chain in the same way:

```
from django.db.models.query_utils import Q

qq = Q()
if category:
    qq = qq | Q(values__something__category__name__iexact=category)
if color:
    qq = qq | Q(values__something__color__name__iexact=color)
something = Something.objects.filter(qq)
```

Comment: hum, pretty easy. This can occurred to me to combine results of filtering in this way :-) Thanks

Comment: I tried this, but if I use date and then category. QuerySet from date is duplicated in category (e.g. 3 results using date and after applying category there should be only 2 records but there is 2*4 - every record is 4x in the QuerySet). It is pretty strange. Can be some problem with version of Django? Ok. it is probably because of joining of tables. Distinct should solve this problem

Comment: I don't think the duplicates come from chaining the filters; don't you see the same duplication with the category query alone? It does relate to joining, and it may be avoidable (depending on the models and on the data that you actually need). But if `distinct()` solves your issue, great.

Comment: Try appending an `order_by()` to the final query, this cancels any default ordering present in the tables involved. If your duplicates disappear then, you've found your culprit. If they don't, it would be interesting to see the models and the queries where this happens.

Answer (score 1):

This is the pattern I use for my custom filtering. If you end up needing more custom implementation around each filter param you could use something like the strategy design pattern which is good to get rid of if-else chains.

```
FILTER_PARAMS = {'from': 'from_date', 'to': 'to_date', 'category': 'values__something__category__name__iexact', 'color': 'values__something__color__name__iexact'}

def get(self):
        filter_params = self.get_filter_params(self.request.query_params)
        qs = queryset.filter(**filter_params)

def get_filter_params(self, query_params):
        fields = {}

        for k, v in query_params.items():
                if k in self.FILTER_PARAMS:
                    fields[self.FILTER_PARAMS[k]] = v
        return fields
```

Comment: Thank @Braden Hold I will check the structure and try it

Comment: No problem. Also replaced tuple with a dictionary so your query_params don't have to match the django filter conventions.